# Left aligned caption for center aligned responsive image part 2

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

@partypete25 and whoever else may be can help!

Thanks for:

[Left aligned caption for center aligned responsive image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113259/left-aligned-caption-for-center-aligned-responsive-image)

and

https://jsfiddle.net/mk7on98L/19/

It's working for me as well! However I cannot seem to have multiple lines of text underneath the image. I tried to use a **BR** and add more lines of text but that errors out. Any suggestions on multiple lines of text with a **BR** at the end of each line of text? Thanks!

I'm trying to use something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <span class="text-center center-block" style="max-width:100%">
        <span data-caption="line 1 of text <br> line 2 of text <br> line 3 of text" class="img-wrapper text-left">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Regards,

Comment: @partypete25 please! =)

Answer (score 0):

I think you were making this two hard on yourself. Just seperate the caption from the image.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <span style="width:100%; margin:0 auto;">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      </span>
      <span class="caption">line 1 of text <br> line 2 of text <br> line 3  of text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! however the image is no longer centered and that doesnt work in mobile views at all =(

Alex Macra- we do have assigned width. Here is the css:

    .img-wrapper {
     display:inline-block;
        max-width:100%;
    }
    .img-wrapper:after {
     content: attr(data-caption);
     text-align:left;
     display:-inline-block;
    }

Comment: @exe, try it now. Adding `margin: 0 auto` should cause it to space automatically regardless of what the center tags are doing.

Comment: Thanks. I added the margin but the photo is still "left aligned".. The concept is to obviously center the photo and then have the text underneath left aligned with the photo being centered. I'm trying to attach a screen shot but I don't think I'm able to here =(

Answer (score 0):

For multiple lines, you'll need to specify a width on .img-wrapper

Comment: we do have assigned width. Here is the css:

    .img-wrapper { display:inline-block; max-width:100%; } .img-wrapper:after { content: attr(data-caption); text-align:left; display:-inline-block; }

Comment: Instead of 100% try a fixed width